# Angular 2 - Toggle button based on JSON response

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

How can we toggle a button to Yes/No based on JSON response in angular 2?

Comment: By writing some code. If you don't even know where to start, then read a book about angular, or the official documentation/tutorial, and practice. If you know where to start, then show what you have tried, and explain the concrete problem you faced. This is much too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to toggle button

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button *ngIf='toggleButton' (click)='toggleButton = false'>Button One</button>
      <button *ngIf='!toggleButton' (click)='toggleButton = true'>Button Two</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  toggleButton: boolean: true; // Flag to toggle your button toggling its value on click of button
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Meta has already decided that we shouldn't answer poor questions, especially questions that are looking to make StackOverflow appear like a code-writing service. This will help to encourage future poor questions flooding the site.

Comment: FYI , i have already posted what i have tried . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065764/toggle-button-based-on-json-response-in-angular-2/46087536?noredirect=1#comment79137331_46087536

Comment: @OptimusPrime why are you posting a duplicate question then? Why did you not link this question in your new question if it is a followup? If this is a duplicate, it should be removed.